# How do I store this string as different variables?

Tags: c++, string, variables

I need to store the first set of digits as a long, and the 2nd set in another long. Then each word has to be stored as a string separately.

Is there a way to do this? The text will just be hardcoded in and not stored on a seperate file, thanks.

1508405807242 1508405807141 one HELLO

Comment: I think they're trying to parse the numbers and individual words in a string.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, you should show your attempts. People will be more willing to help if you show your efforts, especially since the task is rather simple. Also, can't you hardcode directly into different variables?

Answer (score 4):

```
std::string input = "1508405807242 1508405807141 one HELLO";
std::istringstream iss(input);
long a, b;
std::string c, d;
input >> a >> b >> c >> d;
```

Comment: This is correct, but the person asking this question isn't very likely to be a compiler, so it'd help if you could add some text explaining what's going on.